# Does Coca-Cola kill germs in the stomach?

Tags: hygiene

My friend recently went on a trek where his guides suggested he drink Coca Cola to kill any germs in his stomach, so that he didn't get sick. It's given me a skeptical itch. Is there any truth to this?

Comment: According to [this study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17536679) `no effect was observed`. - P.S.: you should find a better source than _'a guy told my friend'_ (see [FAQ: Must all questions be notable?](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable))

Comment: I am pretty sure the hydrochloric acid produced by your stomach works as well...

Comment: Duplicate of http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8360/coca-cola-and-open-water-swimming

Comment: Cola has a strong antibacterial effect on Bacillus cereus, Enterococcus faecalis, Escherichia coli, Salmonella enteritidis, Yersinia enterocolitica bacteria and antifungal effect could not identified per this paper-http://dergi.cumhuriyet.edu.tr/cumuscij/article/viewFile/5000071266/5000097910.

Comment: If anyone thinks this claim is weird, some people think Coca Cola prevents the spread of AIDS. (Protip: use more conventional methods instead)